# Explain a sentence in Hatcher's "Vector Bundles and K-Theory"

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was looking for a proof of this statement

> For any space $X$ the set $[X,SO(n)]$ has a natural group structure coming from the group structure in SO(n). Namely, the product of two maps $f,g:X \rightarrow SO(n)$ is the map $x  \mapsto f(x)g(x)$. Similarly $[X,U(n)]$ is a group.
>   $π_iSO(n)$ and $π_iU(n)$, special cases of the homotopy groups $π_iX$ defined for all spaces X and central to algebraic topology.

at page 27 of this [book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf).

Comment: What are you having trouble with in the proof?

Comment: There is not any proof that the multiplication he puts on is the same of path juxtaposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument)? In particular you want to apply it to the case that $X=S^n$, $n\geq 1$ and the two operations being $*$ given by concatenation of sphere maps, and $\cdot$ given by $(f\cdot g)(x)=f(x)g(x)$. The Eckmann-Hilton argument says that these two group operations coincide and are also abelian.